# Is the case when response is discrete and ordinal classification?

Tags: regression, classification, categorical-data

When predicting the value of a response variable from the value of an explanatory variable, if I am correct,

- when the response is real-valued, the task is regression, and
- when the response takes values from a unordered discrete set, the task is classification.

When the response takes its value from an ordered discrete set, is the task still classification?

For example, let $Y$ be the response variable and $X$ be the explanatory variable. If the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is a Poisson distribution, is the task of predicting the value of $Y$ from the value of $X$ still classification? Is Poisson regression used for classification, just as logistic regression for classification?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check my edit of your title. I changed "and" to "an". It could probably still be improved.

Comment: @NickCox: I used "and", because the response is both discrete and ordinal, and I asked if the case is still classification.

Comment: As you did mean what you said, I've undone my edit. But I doubt that many users would think of Poisson regression as ordinal.

Comment: @NickCox: I thought natural numbers are ordered. What would many users think of Poisson regression as then?

Comment: Just Poisson regression, I guess. If we were re-starting statistics from scratch, most terms would not survive, starting with "regression". But terminology is more about history, psychology, sociology and advertising than some mathematically-based logic.

Comment: Tim - 'ordinal' is usually applied only when a stronger scale doesn't apply. For example, we don't call a geometric distribution "nominal" even though it satisfies all the requirements to be nominal, *because it satisfies all the requirements of a ratio scale*; if we use that ladder of scales, we call it 'ratio'. So no, we don't call the Poisson 'ordinal' because it misleadingly implies that it's not interval or ratio.

Answer (score 7):

Many of your questions (1) are about terminology and (2) seem to presuppose that there is, or should be, a single, simple, correct answer. This attitude is especially optimistic given that use of terminology is usually problematic.

Numerous different statistically minded people in overlapping communities often use the same word in different senses and different words in the same sense. 
Somehow we manage to communicate, but that communication is based largely on realizing that terminology can be tricky, not by identifying unique correct senses for each word. Once past student phase, we don't all go round ingesting dictionaries or learning definitions; we tend up to pick up terminology just from hearing about research (and asking questions when someone else's terms don't seem to match ours). That's a bit inefficient, and misunderstandings often arise, but the alternative of some grand committee deciding what terminology we should all be using is not really practical, or even attractive if they made recommendations that people disliked, which would be inevitable.

In this case, your examples seem easier to discuss concisely than your general assertions.

Is Poisson regression used for classification? That's a factual question, but requiring knowledge of many literatures to answer well. I'd say that's not impossible, but it sounds very unusual.

If the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is a Poisson distribution, is the task of predicting the value of $Y$ from the value of $X$ still classification? Given your definitions, that would be defensible use of terminology, but I'd guess that most people using Poisson regression for prediction do not think of it as classification and would regard that as very odd usage of terms.

The particular case of Poisson regression is very interesting because although the raw data are often integer counts, predicted values typically won't be. Even more, a quiet revolution is slowly extending the use of Poisson regression as a very general method often suitable for non-negative response variables, so if you are presuming that Poisson automatically means a discrete response, that is not a universal assumption.

Much more can be added, as your questions are concise, but reasonable answers have to be longer to take in qualifications. For example, I would not even agree that the main point of logistic regression is classification. Even with 0,1 data it is often as or more fruitful to think of logistic regression as predicting a probability. Whether the analyst wants to use that probability for predicting whether an outcome is 0 or 1 depends on the circumstances. Moreover, logistic regression extends fairly easily to continuous proportions as a response and then the question of classification may never arise.

Comment: Thanks! " most people using Poisson regression for prediction do not think of it as classification". Then what do they think of it as?

Comment: Regression, prediction, modelling: take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

There's some conflicting views in the literature, but it's a matter of terminology. For example: [Frank, E., & Hall, M. A Simple Approach to Ordinal Classification. ECML 2001, 145.](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/ordinal_tech_report.pdf)

I stick to **ordinal classification** because regression makes me think of dependent variables that make sense quantitatively while classification has no assumption over there, with qualitative labels.

Or, intuitively, if you would use a bar graph to visualize the target variable distribution, then it's classification. But if you's use a histogram, it's regression.

In practical terms though there isn't a clear distinction.

Answer (score 1):

If the response is ordinal, then that is a job for (tadam) ordinal regression.

Comment: Thanks! Does Poisson regression belong to ordinal regression?

Comment: Since you can google it faster than I can respond, I will only give you a hint: name comes from the assumed distribution of the response variable ;-)

Comment: I don't understand the hint. Do you mean yes?

Comment: Is a variable with a Poisson distribution an ordinal variable?

Comment: Its range is ordered, but its value has other meanings (counts) beyond just being ordered. I remember ordinal variable has value that has no other meanings besides being ordered? So what is the answer?

Comment: OK, the other way round: does every ordinal variable have a Poisson distribution?

Comment: Not necessarily. What is the answer then?